# Resistance and temperature mathematical relationship of a thermistor

Tags: temperature, electrical-resistance

When I did an experiment measuring the Resistance of a thermistor as I increase or decrease the temperature, when I plot the resistance (y - axis) against temperature (x-axis), I get an exponential decay curve. I know for sure that thermistors have an inverse relationship with temperature and resistance, however I do not know why my graph or experiments shows an exponential decay. Are there any mathematical relationship between resistance and temperature of a thermistor, or previous studies conducted showing the relationship?

Comment: How do you know your curve is an exponential decay and not an inverse temperature decay? What uncertainty analysis did you do to verify this?

Answer (score 0):

> The resistance of a thermistor changes with temperature. How much the resistance changes depends on the type of material used in the thermistor.
>
> Unlike other sensors, thermistors are nonlinear, meaning the points on a graph representing the relationship between resistance and temperature will not form a straight line. The location of the line and how much it changes is determined by the construction of the thermistor.

Refer:
https://www.teamwavelength.com/thermistor-basics/